# OneClass SVM model using pretrained ResNet50 network

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to build OneClass classifier for image recognition. I found [this](https://hackernoon.com/one-class-classification-for-images-with-deep-features-be890c43455d) article, but because I have no full source code I don't exactly understand what am i doing.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=42)

# X_train (2250, 200, 200, 3)
resnet_model = ResNet50(input_shape=(200, 200, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
features_array = resnet_model.predict(X_train)
# features_array (2250, 7, 7, 2048)
pca = PCA(svd_solver='randomized', n_components=450, whiten=True, random_state=42)
svc = SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced')
model = make_pipeline(pca, svc)

param_grid = {'svc__C': [1, 5, 10, 50], 'svc__gamma': [0.0001, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.005]}
grid = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I have 2250 images (food and not food) 200x200px size, I send this data to **predict** method of ResNet50 model. Result is **(2250, 7, 7, 2048)** tensor, any one know what this dimensionality does it mean?

When I try to run grid.fit method i get an error:

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the findings I could make.

You are getting the output tensor above the global average pooling layer. (See `resnet_model.summary()` to know about how input dimension changes to output dimension)

For a simple fix, add an Average pooling 2d Layer on top of resnet_model. 
(So that output shape becomes (2250,1,1, 2048))

```
resnet_model = ResNet50(input_shape=(200, 200, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
resnet_op = AveragePooling2D((7, 7), name='avg_pool_app')(resnet_model.output)
resnet_model = Model(resnet_model.input, resnet_op, name="ResNet")
```

This generally is present in the source code of ResNet50 itself. Basically we are appending an AveragePooling2D layer to the resnet50 model. The last line combines the layer (2nd line) and the base line model into a model object.

Now the output dimension (feature_array) will be `(2250, 1, 1, 2048)` (because of added average pooling layer).

To avoid the `ValueError` you ought to reshape this feature_array to `(2250, 2048)`

```
feature_array = np.reshape(feature_array, (-1, 2048))
```

In the last line of the program in the question,

```
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

you have fit with X_train (which are images in this case). The correct variable here is `features_array` (This is considered to be summary of the image). Entering this line will rectify the error,

```
grid.fit(features_array, y_train)
```

For more finetuning in this fashion by extracting feature vectors do look [here](https://github.com/tlokeshkumar/Fast-image-classification) (training with neural nets instead of using PCA and SVM).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Seems like it working. The only moment I doubt now is - when I want to estimate on new data I should send new photos to ResNet as before to get feature vector? After that I load saved SVC model and run predict method with feature vector?

Comment: Glad that it helped! Yeah, you must send the photo through the network to obtain the feature vector and then use SVM on top of it.

Comment: Yes I see, but I mean how may I deploy such model ? Seems like ResNet features vector relearn every time on the new data I pass to it. I remember when I learned CNN I save its weights and structure so I could load it and I don't need to learn all over again. Here I can save SVC, but it's only 5Mb, as I think the main strength is in features vector.

Comment: I cant understand by what you are meaning by 'ResNet feature vectors are relearning'. The network is non-trainable and hence the weights of ResNet will not change. You can save the model with `model.save()`. Yes, you are right, the strength in SVC is because of ResNet's feature vectors. You must cascade these classifiers as in, Image -> ResNet (Frozen layers) -> SVC -> o/p.